# Flash value cleared when user goes back laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-blade

```
public function create(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->session()->flash('id',$id);
        return view('off.news');
}
```

This flashes the id value which then is used by the store controller function.

If i go to the create page from the first page it passes `-> $id` is flashed

**The problem:**

When i press back to the create page then press submit on create `- >` nothing is passed to `$id.`

I only want it to stay in for one time (not persist).

How do i ensure that the user cant press back to go to the create page?

Comment: I can see that you are passing $id into create method. It means when user open create page then id value will always on URL then why you are flashing it. just use with() to pass id into View

Answer (score 0):

If you have values that you need to pass through from the `create` resource method to the resource `store` method then you should pass those values through the form, you should not use flash data for this. Flash data is useful for passing non-essential information between requests (e.g: success messages), it *is not* suitable for passing information that functionality is dependent on.

For example, your implementation could look something like this:

`create`

```
public function create(int $id)
{
    return view('resource.create', ['resource_id' => $id]);
}
```

`form.blade.php`

```
<form>
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="resource_id" value="{{ $resource_id }}">
  ...
</form>
```

`store`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('resource_id');

    // ...
}
```